# SQL Server Query Won't Commit Using SQLAlchemy Engine

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a process which is writing data to a SQL Server database. All of the queries are running properly except one, which won't commit any data. The code that doesn't commit is below:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from urllib.parse import quote_plus    

connection_parameters = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER={server};" \
                        "DATABASE={Database};TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"
formatted_string = quote_plus(connection_parameters)
connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={0}".format(formatted_string)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string, poolclass=sa.pool.NullPool, echo=True)

sql = ("BEGIN\n"
       "    IF NOT EXISTS (\n"
       "            SELECT [id]\n"
       "            FROM [dbo].[Items]\n"
       "            WHERE [id] = ?\n"
       "            )\n"
       "        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Items] (\n"
       "            [id]\n"
       "            ,[name]\n"
       "            )\n"
       "        VALUES (\n"
       "            ?\n"
       "            ,?\n"
       "            )\n"
       "END")

parameters = (self.identifier, self.identifier, self.title)
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(sql, parameters)
```

Looking at the output of the log I can't see any reason why these rows wouldn't be getting inserted.

```
2016-02-16 08:54:23,288 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT [id]
        FROM [dbo].[Items]
        WHERE [id] = ?
        )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Items] (
        [id]
        ,[Title]
        )
    VALUES (
        ?
        ,?
        )
END
2016-02-16 08:54:23,288 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('0262018020', '0262018020', 
'Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective')
```

Comment: I would recommend moving your t-sql to a stored procedure. It gives you a separation of the data layer and it is a lot easier to code and debug your sql.

Comment: What type is `id` in the database? Is it possible that your strings are losing their leading zeroes as they're being converted to an integer? I don't know enough about your client stack to figure out exactly what's going on in there...

Comment: The column type is `CHAR(10)`.
The table is completely empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried writing a stored procedure. Tried using a `MERGE` statement. The engine just wouldn't write the data. Using a `pyodbc` connection object worked.